# How to search between two dates and diaplay them in the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

So i have two input fields which when i click on, it gives me the calendar. I have two fields. One being from. and the other to. And i have a button labeled "search".

So i was thinking, how would i write the code in laravel to take those two dates, and give me the results in between those two dates? Can i use the "created_at" timestamp on my db to do this? i mean with date picker

Also, how can i use AJAX to load the data to the same page? I have a query to take all the data from a model and display to index function. It is also paginated. So how can i use ajax.

Thanks

**Update:**

Here is what i have so far. Here is my html form:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminViewController@search']) !!}

        <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
        <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
        <input type="submit" id="search" value="Search">

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is my Table (Note: The current foreach loop is taken from my controller to put some sample data):

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Room Number</th>
                    <th>Cleaned By</th>
                    <th>Total Time</th>
                    <th>Supervised</th>
                    <th>Issues</th>
                    <th>Cleaned</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($clean as $cleans)
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{$cleans->roomnumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{$cleans->users->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$cleans->roomnumber}}</td>
                        @if($cleans->verified == 1)<td class="verified">Yes</td>@else()<td class="notverified">No</td>@endif
                        @if($cleans->img1 || $cleans->img1 || $cleans->img1 == !null)<td class="verified">Yes</td>@else()<td class="notverified">No Issues</td>@endif
                        <td>{{$cleans->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{route('starlord.show', $cleans->id)}}"><i class="lnr lnr-eye"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Here is my Routes (Its grouped to admin):

```
    Route::get('/search', 'AdminViewController@search');
    Route::post('/search', 'AdminViewController@search');
```

My controller which handles the search:

```
public function search(Request $request){

        $data =  $request->only(['from', 'to']);
        $data['to'] .= ' 23:59:59';
        $output = Clean::whereBetween('created_at', $data)->get();

        return json_encode($output);
    }
```

And finally here is the AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").click(function(event){ 
                event.preventDefault();


                $.get("/admin/search", function(data, status){
                    console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                });
            });
        });
```

The search result comes perfect when i am simply returning it to a view without ajax. there is no issue with that. But the problem is that when i console log from my ajax, there is a 500 internal error. Here is the error:

```
GET http://test.com/admin/search 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ view:233
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

`(anonymous) @ view:233` is this line:

```
$.get("/admin/search", function(data, status){
```

Why am i not getting the response? If i remove the `event.preventDefault();` from my button, it goes to the `/admin/search` (obviously). I am not too experienced with ajax but i am trying. 
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This is too broad of a question, and you given yourself all the answers, don't expect someone else will write the code for you

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: Basically what you do, create 2 dates inside of `HTML`, send those dates to controller, query the database with `created_at < $end_date` **AND** `created_at > $start_date`, then google how to send ajax request and google `laravel api calls`. boom, you are done

Comment: Laravel has a `whereBetween` function in the query builder. Use that on `cretaed_at`. As Nikola pointed out, you've got all the info you need in the question itself.

Comment: @NikolaGavric I have updated my question and my progress so far. Also undo the down vote XD

Comment: does the code from @PrashantPrajapati works for you?

Comment: Yeah i did try that. But, I'd rather array it in to a variable and send it to the  whereBetween like what i did on my updated question. It's cleaner.

Comment: @NikolaGavric My search is fine from controller. I'm getting the right results. I just do not know how to get it to the view using ajax and append to the current table. I tried the get method which is updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can fetch the data between two dates
For E.g:

```
$start_of_year = Carbon::createFromDate($application->created_at)->startOfYear();
$end_of_year = Carbon::createFromDate($application->created_at)->endOfYear();
//dd($year,$start_of_year,$end_of_year);
$new = Application::where('status','new')
                    ->whereBetween('created_at',
                        [ $start_of_year,$end_of_year])
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is wondering on how to get the data from a `whereBetween` using laravel, my question has been updated.

Here is the fixed and working Json (with comments) for the above question.

```
$(function() {


        $('.form').submit(function(event) {


            // get the form data in value key pair using jquery serialize
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            // get the url we are posting to from the forms action attribute
            //var url  = $(this).attr('/admin/search');

            // process the form
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url: "search", // the url where we want to POST
                data: data, // the url where we want to POST, set in variable above
                dataType: "json", // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                encode          : true,
                 success: function (data) {
                     console.log(data);
                 }
            });



            // using the done promise callback (success)
            // search.done(function(data) {
            //
            //
            //     // log data to the console so we can see
            //     console.log(data);
            //
            //     // here we will handle errors and validation messages
            // });

            // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
            event.preventDefault();

        });//submit function

    });//doc ready end
```

Hope this helps to solve your issue :D